# Index 0 to 1 String Join VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

this code returns the values, but it starts with line 0, and I want to start with line 1. how should I do this?

```
TxtListScanTxt.Lines = nums.Select(Function(b) String.Join(",", b)).ToArray()
```

Textbox1.Text

```
Lines(0)= 1,2,3,4,5,6
Lines(1)= 1,2,3,4,5,7
Lines(2)= 1,2,3,4,5,8
Lines(3)= 1,2,3,4,5,9
Lines(4)= 1,2,3,4,5,10
```

Expected Output:

```
Lines(0)= Empty
Lines(1)= 1,2,3,4,5,6
Lines(2)= 1,2,3,4,5,7
Lines(3)= 1,2,3,4,5,9
Lines(4)= 1,2,3,4,5,10
Lines(5)= 1,2,3,4,5,11
```

Comment: I think I know what you mean but your question is confusing. The title is nonsense, the question is ambiguous and the code and example are inconsistent, e.g. the code uses `TxtListScanTxt` but you then say `Textbox1` and also the data in the expected output is different to the data in what I assume is the actual output. If you want us to volunteer our time to help you, you need to make the effort to provide a clear and accurate question. The two answers so far provided are based on very different interpretations of the question. There should be no room for interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
TxtListScanTxt.Lines = nums.Select(Function(b) String.Join(",", b)).
                            Prepend(String.Empty).
                            ToArray()
```

The `Prepend` method adds one item to the head of an enumerable list. There is also an `Append` method that adds one item to the tail of a list and a `Concat` method that combines two lists into one.

EDIT: If targeting earlier than .NET 4.7.1, you can do this instead:

```
TxtListScanTxt.Lines = {String.Empty}.Concat(nums.Select(Function(b) String.Join(",", b)).ToArray()
```

Obviously that syntax is a bit ugly, which is one reason that `Prepend` was added.

Comment: Prepend is not a member enumerable string (Error message)

Comment: `Prepend` was added in .NET 4.7.1. If you're targeting an earlier version, you can use `Concat` as demonstrated in the edit I'm just about to add, as `Concat` has been around since .NET 3.5.

Comment: I changed Net Framework in 4.7.1 and the first code work good. concat code not worked, i think problem with my code.